# Fetching all (javascript) global variables in a page

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to retrieve the names/values of all global variables on a page?

I would like to write a javascript function to do the following:

1. Find all global variables prefixed with 'xxx_' and stick them in an array (for e.g.)
2. build a query string using the name value pairs as follows:
   xxx_glob_var1=value1&xxx_glob_var2=value2  etc

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (except for the trivial string-building part) [Javascript - dumping all global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369338/javascript-dumping-all-global-variables)

Comment: See this answer to [list all custom properties on `window`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246535/1366033)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function getGlobalProperties(prefix) {
  var keyValues = [], global = window; // window for browser environments
  for (var prop in global) {
    if (prop.indexOf(prefix) == 0) // check the prefix
      keyValues.push(prop + "=" + global[prop]);
  }
  return keyValues.join('&'); // build the string
}
```

A test usage:

```
var xxx_foo = "foo";
xxx_bar = "bar";
window.xxx_baz = "baz";

var test = getGlobalProperties('xxx_');
// test contains "xxx_baz=baz&xxx_bar=bar&xxx_foo=foo"
```

Comment: Why is InputEvent not listed (`getGlobalProperties("Input")`)? That's a global variable, right?

Answer (score 52):

Or you could simply run;

```
Object.keys(window);
```

It will show a few extra globals (~5), but far fewer than the `for (var i in window)` answer.

**Object.keys is available in Chrome 5+, Firefox 4+, IE 9+, and Opera 12, ty  @rink.attendant.6**

Comment: @gsamaras `Object.keys` is available in Chrome 5+, Firefox 4+, IE 9+, and Opera 12+.

Comment: I see @rink.attendant.6, thanks. pleshy, you might want to add this into your answer..

Answer (score 5):

In some cases you may want to find non-[enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) properties; therefore [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) won't work *([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4), [about chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12146473/1615483))* and neither would [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as both only use enumerable keys. Notice that `for..in` is different to [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) but we can't use this to iterate.

Here is a solution using [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) (compatibility is IE9+). I've also added support for when you do only want enumerable properties or if you want to search another in context (not global).

```
function findPrefixed(prefix, context, enumerableOnly) {
    var i = prefix.length;
    context = context || window;
    if (enumerableOnly) return Object.keys(context).filter( function (e) {return e.slice(0,i) === prefix;} );
    else return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(context).filter( function (e) {return e.slice(0,i) === prefix;} );
}
findPrefixed('webkit');
// ["webkitAudioContext", "webkitRTCPeerConnection", "webkitMediaStream", etc..
```

Then if you want to join e.g.

```
findPrefixed('webkit').map(function (e) {return e+'='+window[e];}).join('&');
// "webkitAudioContext=function AudioContext() { [native code] }&webkitRTCPeerConnection=function RTCPeerConnection() etc..
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
for (var i in window) {
    // i is the variable name
    // window[i] is the value of the variable
}
```

Though with this, you'll get a bunch of extra DOM properties attached to window.

Comment: `Object.keys(window);` shows far fewer extra DOM properties.

Comment: @DanDascalescu still over 200 so it's not useful when wanting to get objects created only by your script

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the two top answers didn't work, thus I am adding another answer, to highlight the comment of Dan Dascalescu:

```
Object.keys(window);
```

When I executed it, it gave:

> top,location,document,window,external,chrome,$,jQuery,matchMedia,jQuery1113010234049730934203,match_exists,player_exists,add_me,isLetter,create_match,delete_me,waiting,unsure,refresh,delete_match,jsfunction,check,set_global,autoheight,updateTextbox,update_match,update_player,alertify,swal,sweetAlert,save_match,$body,value_or_null,player,position,ability,obj_need_save,xxx_saves,previousActiveElement

where the player, positon, ability, obj_need_save, xx_saves are my actual global variables.

---

I just saw that there exists a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369361/2411320) to another question.