# Javascript - dumping all global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in Javascript to get a list or dump the contents of all global variables declared by Javascript/jQuery script on a page? I am particularly interested in arrays. If I can get the array names, it will be enough to me. Seeing its values is a bonus.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
Object.keys( window );
```

This will give you an Array of all *enumerable* properties of the `window` object, (which are global variables).

For older browsers, include [the compatibility patch from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

---

To see its values, then clearly you'll just want a typical enumerator, like `for-in`.

---

You should note that I mentioned that these methods will only give you ***enumerable*** properties. Typically those will be ones that are not built-in by the environment.

It is possible to add *non-enumerable* properties in ES5 supported browsers. These will not be included in `Object.keys`, or when using a `for-in` statement.

---

As noted by [@Raynos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419970/raynos), you can  `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( window )` for non-enumerables. I didn't know that. Thanks @Raynos!

So to see the values that include enumerables, you'd want to do this:

```
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( window ),
    value;

for( var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i ) {
    value = window[ keys[ i ] ];
    console.log( value );
}
```

Comment: You can also use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( window )` for non-enumerables

Comment: On Chrome, some of `window`'s properties inherit from `Window.prototype` and `Window`. They're accessible as globals, but you'll need to concat together `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` results on `window`, `Window`, and `Window.prototype`

Comment: also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17246535/4040525 Combining both of them worked great for me

Comment: it does not work. `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Answer (score 5):

The following function only dumps global variables that have been *added* to the window object:

```
(function(){
    //noprotect <- this comment prevents jsbin interference
    var windowProps = function() {
        // debugger;
        var result = {};
        for (var key in window) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, key)) {
                if ((key|0) !== parseInt(key,10)) {
                    result[key] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        window.usedVars = result;
    };

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.src = 'about:blank'; 
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    var fwin = iframe.contentWindow;
    var fdoc = fwin.document;
    fdoc.open('text/html','replace');
    fdoc.write('<!DOCTYPE html><body><script>window.onload = ' + windowProps.toString() + '<\u002Fscript>');
    fdoc.close();

    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.value = 'go';
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    button.onclick = function() {
        var clean = fwin.usedVars;
        windowProps();
        var dirty = window.usedVars;
        for (var key in clean) {
            delete dirty[key];
        }
        for (var variable in dirty) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.textContent = variable;
            document.body.appendChild(div);     
        }
        document.body.removeChild(button);
        document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    };
})();
```

It works by using an iframe to get a clean list of global window variables, then comparing that with the list of global variables in the current window. It uses a button because the iframe runs asynchronously. The code uses a global variable because that makes the code easier to understand.

You can see it working [here](https://output.jsbin.com/quhano/) or [here](https://jsbin.com/quhano/edit), although note that these examples show many global variables "leaked" by jsbin itself (different depending on which link you use).

Answer (score 3):

Since all global variables are properties of the `window` object, you can get them using:

```
for(var key in window) { // all properties
    if(Array.isArray(window[key])) { // only arrays
        console.log(key, window[key]); // log key + value
    }
}
```

Since all default/inherited properties are not plain arrays (mostly host objects or functions), the `Array.isArray` check is sufficient.

Comment: "all global variables are properties of the window object"; `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

???

Answer (score 2):

You can use npm package called [get-globals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-globals). It compares properties of `window` with fresh-created `iframe` to print only variables declared by dev(s), not browser vendor.

Answer (score 1):

`window` is the global object in a browser, and you can use a `for..in` loop to loop through its properties:

```
if(!Array.isArray) {
    Array.isArray = function(obj) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]';
    };
}

for(var x in window) {
    if(Array.isArray(window[x])) {
        console.log('Found array ' + x + ' in ' + window + ', it has the value ' + window[x] + '!');
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it is a fairly old answer, but `'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.`

Answer (score 1):

To get "globals" object you can use this function:

```
function globals() { return this; }
```

Here is the test:
http://jsfiddle.net/EERuf/

Comment: Not strict mode compliant, by the way :)

Comment: Um... because it's true? Take a look at this on an ES5-compatible browser: http://jsfiddle.net/G95gQ/

Comment: @c-smile In strict mode when there is no context, `this` is `null`. It's not the global object.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: And finally, to be nitpicky, it's not `null`, it's `undefined` :)

Comment: Isn't this just the same as using `this` globally? `this === globals()` evaluates to `true` in both the Firefox and Node consoles because `this` globally is just the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object).

Answer (score 0):

Greasymonkey script to get leaked globals

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        SCI
// @namespace   ns
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==
console.log('SCI loaded');
var SCI = window.SCI = {
        defprops: [],
        collect: function(){
            var wprops = [];
            for(var prop in window){
                wprops.push(prop);
            }
            return wprops;
        },
        collectDef: function(){
            this.defprops = this.collect(); 
        },
        diff: function(){
            var def = this.defprops,
                cur = this.collect();
            var dif = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < cur.length; i++){
                var p = cur[i];
                if(def.indexOf(p) === -1){
                    dif.push(p);
                }
            }
            return dif;
        },
        diffObj: function(){
            var diff = this.diff();
            var dobj = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < diff.length; i++){
                var p = diff[i];
                dobj[p]=window[p];
            }
            return dobj;

        }
};
SCI.collectDef();
```

To use run in console `SCI.diff()` to get list of names or `SCI.diffObj()` to get object with variables

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a simple, more modern snippet that logs an object with the globals *and* their values (rather than just the global variable names), which is usually what I’m looking for when debugging:

```js
(function () {
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    iframe.setAttribute('hidden', '')
    iframe.src = 'about:blank'
    iframe.onload = function () {
        // Iterate through the properties of the current `window` and reduce the output
        // to only properties that are not in the iframe’s `window`.
        console.debug(Object.entries(window).reduce((reducedObj, [property, value]) => {
            // Check if the property does not exist in the iframe and if so, add it to
            // the output object.
            if (! (property in iframe.contentWindow))
                reducedObj[property] = value
            return reducedObj
        }, {})))
        // Clean up the iframe by removing it from the DOM.
        iframe.remove()
    }
    // Append the iframe to the DOM to kick off loading.
    document.body.append(iframe)
})()
```

*Tip: You can also swap `'about:blank'` with `window.location` to get only the globals set since the page was first loaded.*

This uses an iframe to determine which properties to ignore like [robocat’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36323842/4922436), but it’s based on [David Walsh’s solution](https://davidwalsh.name/global-variables-javascript).