# Easy way to dump window object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a bug logger script for my javascript application.  What I would like to do is to attach javascript environment variables to the bug reports (e.g. window.*).

Is there a convenient way to do this in javascript?

Comment: In my browser (Chrome) on this page, there are 539 attributes of `window`, many of which are complex objects. You want them *all* logged, with their values?

Comment: You should think of putting your env variables in one common namespace.

Comment: For example, there's a bunch of constructors and static classes, some unassigned event handlers, several browser-defined utility functions...

Comment: Actually, yeah, that's what I want

Comment: `for(i in window) console.log(i, window[i])` -- Is this what you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - dumping all global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369338/javascript-dumping-all-global-variables)

Comment: How do you intend to log complex values, like functions? You're going to wind up with tens of thousands of lines of logging. You're also going to have to dodge recursion, which is particularly hard, as (for the simplest example) `window.window.window.window....` is a thing.

Comment: Your question's title mentions "dump window object" but then your actual question then mentions "attach".  So which is it; attach or dump?

Comment: There's also the non-trivial issue that navigation to a cross-browser's frame scope kills your script in a way you cannot prevent, easily predict or recover from.

Comment: @KenrickChien the bug report is being attached to, not the window object.