# Is there a way to differentiate between a global variable and an original window property?

Tags: javascript

For example, `window.location` is an original browser-defined property.  But if I say `window.test = "Hello";` that is a global variable, set by my custom JavaScript.  Is there a way in JavaScript to differentiate between the two?

For context, my ultimate goal is to output a list of global variables, for debugging purposes but something like `Object.keys(window);` outputs both the browser-defined properties and the custom ones.

Comment: No. There's no user-visible way to tell the difference.

Comment: they're both global, your browser doesn't know who's set them. You can do all kinds of stuff to be done with scopes though. Or if you'd really want to; make a copy of the window object _before_ you do anything with it, and check which variables are new by comparing the current `window` object with the original one

Comment: I mean, you could try deleting them (e.g., `delete window.location` will return false), but I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the dupe! I found the answer I needed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246535/738394