# How to get variables names inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I want to get "a, b" in this example https://jsfiddle.net/8dw9e5k7/ instead I get something else. Is it possible ?

```
    function test() {

        a = 5;
        b = 10;
        try {
          var variables = ""
          for (var name in this)
          variables += name + "\n";
          alert(variables);
        } catch(e) {
          alert(e.message)
        }
        
    }

    test();
```

Comment: it is not possible to get the used variables of the actual function uless you take the function as string and parse it. btw, why using `this` with global variables?

Comment: if necessary you can put your variables inside an object of your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning non-existent variables in a function makes the variables **global** which means attached to the `window` object. That's why your code works somewhat and displays the variables along with many other things, because `this` refers to `window`.

Dumping your own variables attached to `window` is not possible in a clean way (some hacks still exist which consist in creating a fresh `window` with an `iframe` and compare it to the current `window`, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246309/get-all-user-defined-window-properties#answer-17246535) if you're interested)

Now if you're expecting `this` to refer to the lexical scope of the current function, it's not the case and you can't retrieve it programmatically at all.