# Non-enumerable properties appear in for...in loop in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

A `for`-`in` loop will go through all enumerable properties of an object, even those in the prototype chain. The function `hasOwnProperty` can filter out those enumerable properties that are in the prototype chain. Finally, the function `propertyIsEnumerable` can discriminate the enumerable properties of an object.

Therefore, the following script **should not print anything**:

```
for(a in window)
    if(window.hasOwnProperty(a) && !window.propertyIsEnumerable(a))
        console.log(a);
```

On Chrome, however, the above prints *a lot* of property names.

Why do the `for`-`in` loop and `propertyIsEnumerable` contradict each other regarding enumerables?

Comment: Zero properties printed for me on Firefox 14 ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGWj7/)).

Comment: Remember that `window` is **host** variable and does not have to follow the specification exactly.

Comment: @Felix, do you mean the enumerated object itself chooses how to filter its properties when `for ... in` is applied to it?

Comment: @FelixKling: Hum. Can you point to the part of the specification for that? :)

Comment: Yes, this is weird. `window.propertyIsEnumerable('Int8Array')` is false, but `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'Int8Array').enumerable` is true. According to the specs, they should be equal.

Comment: http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.8 host objects do not necessarily follow the spec.

Comment: The host object thing is [allowed](http://es5.github.com/#x8.6.2), though: "Host objects may support these internal properties with any implementation-dependent behaviour" - that is for `[[GetOwnProperty]]` which is the descriptor containing `enumerable`.

Comment: For example: *"Host objects may implement these internal methods in any manner unless specified otherwise; for example, one possibility is that [[Get]] and [[Put]] for a particular host object indeed fetch and store property values but [[HasProperty]] always generates false."* http://es5.github.com/#x8.6.2. I'm not saying that is the case here, it might be indeed a bug, but it has to be kept in mind.

Comment: The global object is a *standard built-in* object, **not** a *host object*. Its properties may well be, but that should not affect `for-in` loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sad fact is that JavaScript engines are not the same. While ES5 conforming engines will dutifully respect the enumerability of their properties, `window` is a host object, as pointed out by pimvdb and Felix above, and not beholden to the rules of ES5.

You can see more evidence of what `window` object actually is in `window.constructor`, which will show it as being constructed from

```
function Window() { [native code] }
```

As such, we have no real way of determining why certain properties are enumerable (according to Chrome), and others are not from within the JavaScript runtime.

However, you can still see the full state of Chrome's inconsistent `window` enumerable properties by looking at `Object.keys(window)` which according to [its MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), "returns an array of all own enumerable properties found upon a given object."

Doing so still returns an array of 30-odd properties. Chalk it up to Chrome strangeness!

EDIT: With some further testing, I found the proper way for Chrome to make sense as to `window`'s enumerable properties

```
Object.keys(window).filter(function(prop) {
  return window.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !window.propertyIsEnumerable(prop);
});
```

It would seem that in Chrome, the candidate list of properties for enumeration by `for...in` is NOT what is returned by `Object.keys`, but actually much closer to `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` which lists enumerable and non-enumerable properties. However, even that is inconsistent. The list of properties that are `window.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !window.propertyIsEnumerable(prop)` come out to 423 and 454 for `for...in` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, respectively, in my testing.

Comment: What's even weirder is that I'm only seeing 8 properties with `Object.keys`. Perhaps it should be seen as a bug :)

Comment: Even weirder is the inconsistent behavior of ``for...in`` on Chrome when it comes to enumerability of host properties.
I found another test with inconsistent results.

Comment: Fiddling with it, I found that Chrome does in fact seem to honour `hasOwnProperty` when using `Object.keys`. That is, `return !window.propertyIsEnumerable(prop);` is enough. Still, this shouldn't be necessary of course.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is weird:

```
for(a in window)
    if(window.hasOwnProperty(a) && window.propertyIsEnumerable(a))
        console.log(a);
```

It puts out about 30 properties compared to like 450 the other way, in chrome.

Comment: You would not need `hasOwnProperty` at all - only own property will be tested as enumerable