# Why I am not able to see `length` property of arguments objects in `console.log` ouput?

Tags: javascript

All I can see are indexes and values. Other properties like length or callee are not displayed. How to hide properties from console.log()? And how to see all the properties?

For example:

```
function test(){
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log(arguments.length);
}

test(1,2,3,4,5);
```

The output is `{ '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4, '4': 5 }` and `5`

Actually there is `length` property in arguments but I cannot see in `console.log(arguments)`.

Comment: San you add some code and output ?
You are not really accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `arguments.length` property is non-enumerable.

You can define a property on an object and set its [`enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute) attribute to `false`, like this

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
    "value": "a",
    enumerable: false
});

console.log(obj);
// {}
```

You can check the same with [`Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) function, like this

```
function testFunction() {
    console.log(arguments.propertyIsEnumerable("length"));
}

testFunction();
```

would print `false`, because `length` property of `arguments` special object is not enumerable.

If you want to see all the properties, use the answers mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8024149/1903116). Basically, **[`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) can enumerate even the non-enumerable properties**. So, you can use that like this

```
function testFunction() {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arguments).forEach(function (currentProperty) {
        console.log(currentProperty, arguments[currentProperty]);
    });
}

testFunction();
```

this would print the `length` and the `callee` properties.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm trying your code. I found Object.defineProperty works well in Node.js. I cannot see property name (the default value of enumerable is false). But in chrome, I can still see {name:a}.

Comment: @MatthewMa Oh that.... Please check [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12146473/1903116)