# How to find the global variables used in my javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetching all (javascript) global variables in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226007/fetching-all-javascript-global-variables-in-a-page)

My application is using global variables in javascript. Is there a way to find how many of them are there?

Thanks
Om

Comment: The easiest way would be to inspect the `window` object.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to set global variables? I'm trying to think of a case where that would be necessary, but I can't come up with one.

Comment: @Thomas: When we designed the application initially we used it and now i am trying to remove and make them local..

Comment: @Ohm - can you clarify... do you want to get a list of all global vars, or just the ones that you're creating? I read this question as "how can I tell which global vars are mine so I can get rid of them" in which case I think the mods closed the question prematurely.

Answer (score 14):

I made one.

```
var GlobalTester = (function(){
    var fields = {};
    var before = function(w){
        for(var field in w){
            fields[field] = true;
        };
    };

    var after = function(w){
        for(var field in w){
            if(!fields[field]){
                 console.log(field + " has been added");
            }            
        };

    };
    return {before: before, after:after};
}());

GlobalTester.before(window);

// Run your code here        
window.blar = "sdfg";      

GlobalTester.after(window);        
​
​
```

This will output `blar has been added` in the console

Answer (score 8):

Try this in your browser developer window (F12):

```
Object.keys(window).length
```

Comment: +1 for [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: This will return a count of all of the properties of this window, not just the ones that the OP is interested in.

Comment: Closed so I can't answer; Also look at using [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) if any of the globals you're adding might not be enumerable.

Comment: Ah - no worries. I might have misread the question. I thought he wanted to know how many global variables there were. Not exactly how many his code was using. I'd probably look to JSLint/JSHint for that.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the window element like this:

```
for(var globe in window){
 console.log(globe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a linter would warn you when globals are introduced. You could also compare items of `window` before and after your code runs.

Answer (score -2):

Inspect the window object, but you will need to know all of the global variable names before you do this, here is an example:

```
var myGlobalVars = {"global1":0, "global2":0};

function countGlobals() {
    var count = 0;
    for (myGlobalVar in myGlobalVars) {
        if (myGlobalVar in window) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

countGlobals();
```

Comment: After thinking about it, I understand your concern, since you can just count the number of properties in the globalVars variable.  But as I interpreted this question, the properties may or may not be there, so this answer is justified.

Comment: If the OP knows the names of all their global variables, why would they ask the question?

Comment: In case the global variables are allocated at some unknown point during run-time, but the names of the variables are known during "compile" time.