# Saving variables in local HTML

Tags: html

I am making a html file for myself and want to be able to enter variables then close the program and when I open it agian it will still remember the variable without me having to enter it again? Is this possible to do

Comment: with Javascript, yes. With HTML, no.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it with JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save all JavaScript variables on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484532/save-all-javascript-variables-on-a-page)

Comment: Did you do it?

Don't forget to mark my answer as Correct Answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can set and get variables from local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("Key", "Value");

alert(localStorage.getItem("Key"));
```

This will display Value on the screen.