# How to run JavaScript function in browser console?

Tags: javascript, function, browser, console

In my Python program, I need to run the hcaptchaCallback function (screenshot), but the function name has a different numbers each time. Can I somehow run this function by specifying only the first part of the name (hcaptchaCallback)?

```
driver.execute_script('hcaptchaCallback...()')
```

[image]

Comment: There is no built in way to really do that. You could do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226007/fetching-all-javascript-global-variables-in-a-page and do a match with starts with with find()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that lets you really do that. You might be able to pull off looping over the globals and looking for a variable that starts with your string.

```js
window[Object.keys(window).find(k=>k.startsWith("hcaptchaCallback"))]();
```

that will call it the way you showed, but looking at the function signature, looks like you are going to have to use [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)